# Query with JSON array in WHERE in Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, jsonb

I have a user model with a payment_info JSONB column that contains the following json example:

```
{
    "customer_id": "cst_K5gCsCkKAU",
    "subscriptions": [
        {
            "status": "active",
            "external_id": "sub_3Q9Q4bP2zW"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am a newbie with JSON queries, but created the following against the Postgres (PG) db that seem to work, that is: I search for all users that has a certain external_id value:

```
SELECT payment_info->'subscriptions' as Subscriptions
    FROM public."user"
    , jsonb_array_elements(payment_info->'subscriptions') as subs
    where (subs->>'external_id')::text = 'sub_3Q9Q4bP2zW'
```

How do I do the same in SQLAlchemy? I tried several thinks that I found on the web (SO) but it does't work. I tried:

1. [JSONB Comparator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator)

   ```
   query = misc.setup_query(db_session, User).filter(
       User.payment_info.comparator.contains(
           ('subscriptions', 'external_id') == payment_subscription_id))
   ```

   That results in following error:

   ```
   sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: jsonb @> boolean
   LINE 3: WHERE "user".payment_info @> false
                                 ^
   HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
   ```
2. `json_contains` function:

   ```
   from sqlalchemy import func
   query = misc.setup_query(db_session, User).filter(
       func.json_contains(User.payment_info,
                          payment_subscription_id,
                          ['subscriptions', 'external_id']))
   ```

   That results in:

   ```
   LINE 3: WHERE json_contains("user".payment_info, 'sub_QxyMEmU', ARRA...
              ^
   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
   ```
3. Path to the key:

   ```
   query = misc.setup_query(db_session, User).filter(
       User.payment_info['subscriptions', 'external_id'].astext == payment_subscription_id)
   ```

   That results in empty result, with the following query:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM "user" 
   WHERE ("user".payment_info #>> %(payment_info_1)s) = %(param_1)s
   ```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make it work? BTW: Do I need to put an index on the `external_id`? (not present yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pretty much implement your original approach using an [aliased function expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.alias):

```
misc.setup_query(db_session, User).\
    select_from(
        User,
        func.jsonb_array_elements(User.payment_info['subscriptions']).
            alias('subs')).\
    filter(column('subs', type_=JSONB)['external_id'].astext == 'sub_3Q9Q4bP2zW')
```

which compiles to

```
SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".payment_info AS user_payment_info 
FROM "user", jsonb_array_elements("user".payment_info -> %(payment_info_1)s) AS subs 
WHERE (subs ->> %(subs_1)s) = %(param_1)s
```

On the other hand you could use the [containment operator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSONB.Comparator.contains):

```
misc.setup_query(db_session, User).\
    filter(User.payment_info['subscriptions'].contains(
        [{'external_id': 'sub_3Q9Q4bP2zW'}]))
```

Note that the outermost list is required, as it is part of the "path" to check. With that same logic you could omit extracting the array:

```
misc.setup_query(db_session, User).\
    filter(User.payment_info.contains(
        {'subscriptions': [{'external_id': 'sub_3Q9Q4bP2zW'}]}))
```

The above `@>` using approaches are indexable using a [GIN index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). The 1st requires a functional index, because it extracts the array first:

```
CREATE INDEX user_payment_info_subscriptions_idx ON "user"
USING GIN ((payment_info -> 'subscriptions'));
```

The 2nd would require indexing the entire `payment_info` jsonb column. Creating GIN indexes can be done in SQLAlchemy model definitions with [Postgresql-specific index options](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-specific-index-options):

```
class User(Base):
    ...

Index('user_payment_info_subscriptions_idx',
      User.payment_info['subscriptions'],
      postgresql_using='gin')
```

---

As to why the various attempts proved unsuccessful:

1. You're not supposed to access the comparator directly. It provides the operators for the type. In addition you're passing `contains()` the result of the expression

   ```
    ('subscriptions', 'external_id') == payment_subscription_id
   ```

   which is False, most likely (depends on what `payment_subscription_id` is). That is to say it is evaluated *in Python*.
2. [There is no `json_contains()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) in Postgresql (unlike MySQL). Use the `@>` operator, or SQL/JSON path functions, such as `jsonb_path_exists()`.
3. You have the wrong path. `User.payment_info['subscriptions', 'external_id'].astext` would match something like `{"subscriptions": {"external_id": "foo"}}`, but in your data `subscriptions` references an array.

Comment: Whaauuu, I am impressed. Thanks a lot. In the meantime I got it working as "raw" sql. I found it difficult to found good information about this topic, especially if it concerns an json array. Both seem to work out-of-the-box, which one performs better? Or should I prefer? Do I need to put an index on the "external_id"? and if so, how do I do that?

Comment: In general it's challenging to answer questions about performance without your data. But I've a hunch that given enough data and the indexes in place the `@>` approach wins.

Comment: Thanks again (sorry about the index comment question, overlooked when writting :(

Comment: Concerning the  Index: I am using the containment operator, and you mention that the Index should be on the complete payment_info jsonb column. Why is that? And should it be like this?: Index('user_payment_info_subscriptions_idx',payment_info, postgresql_using='gin')

Comment: It depends on how you choose to query. If you first extract the array and then check containment, you need the functional index on the extracted path only. If you check containment starting from the root, you need to index the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks llja. I probably wasn't clear in my last comment, but I am using the containment construction from the root (the 2d query in your reply), so I suppose that this index is correct not?: Index('user_payment_info_subscriptions_idx',payment_info, postgresql_using='gin')

Comment: Yeppers, that index works for `User.payment_info.contains({'subscriptions': [{'external_id': 'sub_3Q9Q4bP2zW'}]})`.